# Intellij idea не компилирует задачу

Tags: java, компиляция, intellij-idea

Идея не компилирует задачу если присутствуют классы сохраненные в отдельном файле. Как решить проблему?[image: Пример ошибки]

Основной класс

```
package com.javarush.test.level14.lesson08.home09;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;

public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Person ivan = new Person("Иван");
        for (Money money : ivan.getAllMoney())
        {
            System.out.println(ivan.name + " имеет заначку в размере "
                    + money.getAmount() + " " + money.getCurrencyName());
        }
    }

    static class Person
    {
        public String name;

        Person(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.allMoney = new ArrayList<Money>();
            this.allMoney.add(new Hrivna(1));
            this.allMoney.add(new USD(3));



            //Add your code here
        }

        private List<Money> allMoney;

        public List<Money> getAllMoney()
        {
            return allMoney;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс Money

```
package com.javarush.test.level14.lesson08.home09;

public abstract class Money
{
    private double amount;

    public Money(double amount)
    {
        amount = this.amount;
    }

    public double getAmount(){
        return amount;
    };

    public abstract String getCurrencyName();
}
```

Класс USD

```
package com.javarush.test.level14.lesson08.home09;

/**
 * Created by Efimov_V on 28.07.2015.
 */
public class USD extends Money
{
    public USD(double amount)
    {
        super(amount);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrencyName()
    {
        return "USD";
    }
}
```

Comment: в файл Solution.java нужно добавить строку с импортом файла Money.java.

Да, и прикладывать скриншоты - далеко не самый лучший способ публикации кода.

Comment: Уберите скриншот и добавьте код.

Comment: @Владимир, там же ещё ошибка показывается и набор файлов. По-моему, в данном случае скриншот удобнее.

Comment: Чтобы найти ответ, нужен код класса Money. Подозреваю, что вы неправильно объявили класс. В результате этого он не распознается в классе Solution. Добавьте код в вопрос, тогда его снова откроют и можно будет отвечать.

Comment: @Qwertiy: там ошибка в файле, кода которого нет на скриншоте.

Comment: добавьте импорт файлов правильно.

Comment: @KoVadim, импортировать классы, которые лежат в том же пакете необязательно. Почему тогда IDEA не выдаёт ошибки на классы USD и Hrivna? Тут что-то другое...

Comment: @ForestThule, stacktrace ошибки тоже лучше показывать как блок кода, а не как скриншот с IDE.

Comment: Собрал проект по файлам. Все скомпилировалось. Странно, что ищет файлы оно в другой папке. Именно поэтому я и писал - добавить правильно импорт. 

Может не стоит делать все в одной куче, а завести для каждого проекта отдельный проект?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте, очистить и пересобрать проект. По импортам всё хорошо. Т.к. класс `Money` находится в том же пакете, что и класс `Solution`, то дополнительно импортировать его в `Solution` не нужно.
Я собрал проект с таким же пакетом, с Вашим кодом и всё работает:

```
Иван имеет заначку в размере 0.0 Hrivna
Иван имеет заначку в размере 0.0 USD
```

Небольшой совет: если результат `getCurrencyName()` всегда совпадает с именем валюты (а значит, именем класса), то достаточно в классе `Money` описать метод, который будет возвращать имя класса:

```
public String getCurrencyName(){
    return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

(почитайте про [рефлексию](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api) в Java)

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне не понятно каким образом "пересобрать проект". Задачи мы получаем через плагин.

Comment: Задача из курса JavaRush

Comment: @ForestThule, Build -> Rebuild Project. Ещё могу посоветовать проверить, какой класс ты запускаешь в качестве главного. Для этого проверь конфигурацию конфигурацию (Run -> Edit Configurations). Там в поле **Main class** должно быть установлено значение: `com.javarush.test.level14.lesson08.home09.Solution`.

Comment: Удалил все старые задачи, а их там больше 50 и пересобрал проект - все заработало